# How do I open multiple documents in Adobe Reader X in tabbed form?

Tags: adobe-reader

I have one PDF open and I want to open any other PDF's after that in a tab beside the first PDF.  How do I do it?  Also, How do I set it as a default function?

Answer (score 8):

Tabbed viewing isn't supported by Adobe Reader X. Instead, you can open documents in different Window of the app.

**Update:**
If you don't mind dropping Adobe Reader X, install [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/). It does support tabbed viewing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open documents in Adobe Reader in a tab – but instead it will always open in a window.

If you want to work with more than one opened document, what you can do is on the task bar, on the time and date, right click, then from the menu click "Show windows side by side" then all your opened windows will be aligned vertically.